# Pass a url as a parameter in Ruby on Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I'm trying to pass an audio URL as a parameter in Ruby on Rails, and googling "how to pass a url in a url" has proved to be problematic. The problem is that I can only get the url to return minus a crucial forward slash.

My route looks like:

```
get 'my_page/:title/*url', to: 'my_page', action: 'show'
```

The variable is defined in the controller like so:

```
@url=params[:url]
```

So the request would look like:

```
www.my_app.com/my_page/im_a_title/http://im_a_url.mp3
```

The url variable, however, ultimately results missing a slash after the prefix:

```
http:/im_a_url.mp3 <--notice the missing forward slash
```

Of note, the construction of the urls varies enough that it would be cumbersome to construct them. (Some begin with http and some https, for instance.) How do I preserve the syntax of my url? Or is there a better way to pass this parameter all together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you pass the url as a required parameter. That way you can use the built-in `to_query`.

```
get 'files/:title' => 'files#show'
```

and in files controller

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    url = params.fetch(:url) # throws error if no url
  end

end
```

You can encode the url and unencode like so:

```
{ url: 'http://im_a_url.mp3' }.to_query
# => "url=http%3A%2F%2Fim_a_url.mp3"
Rack::Utils.parse_query "url=http%3A%2F%2Fim_a_url.mp3"
# => {"url"=>"http://im_a_url.mp3"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should url encode the parameters before passing them in

Comment: Yes, thank you, very close. Although, now I'm not getting the .mp3 suffix.

Answer (score 1):

`Rails 4`

```
match 'my_page/:title/:url', to: 'my_page#show' , constraints: { url: /[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}/}, via: :get, :format => false
```

1. `constraints` will match only a regex for a url.
2. `format => false` will ignore the dot part of the url